# Is the length of Facetime calls made with Apple Watch recorded?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, facetime

If I make a Facetime audio call with my Apple Watch, is there a record of the time date and length of that call stored on the iPhone.

Answer (score -2):

It will, as you call with your phone to make the call.